# Textbook exercise-ARMA model

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima, stationarity, lags

I have tried hard but cannot solve the below exercise. Any extra hint or solution will be appreciated!

Given the below stationary series:
\begin{align*}
y_t=\frac{L-\phi}{1-\phi L}\varepsilon_t,
\end{align*}

where $L$ is the lag operator, $|\phi|<1$ and $\varepsilon_t\sim WN(0, \sigma^2)$. If we know $y_t$ is a ARMA($p, q$) series, please find the value of $p$ and $q$. (Hint: $y_t$ is NOT the ARMA($1,1$) series.)

---

What I understand so far is shown as below:

By rearranging the equation, we have
\begin{align*}
(1-\phi L)y_t=(L-\phi)\varepsilon_t \Rightarrow y_t=\phi y_{t-1}-\phi\varepsilon_t+\varepsilon_{t-1}.
\end{align*}
Then why is it not ARMA($1,1$)?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Thank you for your kind remind. I have updated what I tried so far. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: ARMA(1,1) has $\varepsilon_t$, not $\phi\varepsilon_t$. But perhaps you could redefine the error term e.g. $u_t:=\varepsilon_t/\phi$, then it would look like an ARMA(1,1) in terms of $y$ and $u$.